# Sum value from different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, series

i've got this series which come from from different dataframe:

```
10    1193.036
Name: tempo, dtype: float64
8    540.226
Name: tempo, dtype: float64
9    1130.245
Name: tempo, dtype: float64
7    702.232
Name: tempo, dtype: float64
9    815.678
Name: tempo, dtype: float64
2    864.336
Name: tempo, dtype: float64
3    880.07
Name: tempo, dtype: float64
2    837.018
Name: tempo, dtype: float64
2    986.842
Name: tempo, dtype: float64
1    1080.287
Name: tempo, dtype: float64
1    1086.674
Name: tempo, dtype: float64
```

To obtain this series I've done this:

```
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

for f in csv_files:
    dfDay = pd.read_csv(f, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", sep = ';')
    dfSlotSum = dfDay.groupby('slot', as_index=False)['tempo'].sum()
    slotMorningSum = dfSlotSum[dfSlotSum.slot == '7--8']
     
    if slotMorningSum.empty:
        continue   
   
    print(slotMorningSum['tempo'])
```

How can i sum every single value? if i do slotMorningSum['tempo'].sum() what I've obtain in output is:

```
1193.036
540.226
1130.245
702.2320000000001
815.678
864.3360000000001
880.07
837.018
986.842
1080.2869999999998
1086.674
```

that are same value obtained before(I also tried with for loop but the output it's still the same). How can i sum this value?

Comment: What's missing here is a way to collect things up, one way is to create a `List` variable before the for loop, then in the for loop you `append` all those `slotMorningSum['tempo']` into the `List`, lastly, you combine them using `pd.concat` and do the `sum()`.

Comment: I probably did something wrong  list_=[] 
    for i in slotMorningMean['tempo']:
        list_.append(i)
    concate = pd.concat(list_)
    
    print(concate.sum())

Comment: `list_=[]` ok, you need `list_.append(slotMorningSum)` . then after the loop, you do `concate = pd.concat(list_)` and  `print(concate.sum())`

Comment: like this?   (`list_ = [] 
    list_.append(slotMorningSum)
    for i in slotMorningSum['tempo']:
        concate = pd.concat(list_) 
        print(concate.sum()) `)

Comment: Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

#What's missing here is a way to collect things up, one way is to create a `List` variable before the for loop,
list_ = []

for f in csv_files:
    dfDay = pd.read_csv(f, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", sep = ';')
    dfSlotSum = dfDay.groupby('slot', as_index=False)['tempo'].sum()
    slotMorningSum = dfSlotSum[dfSlotSum.slot == '7--8']
     
    if slotMorningSum.empty:
        continue 

    #then in this for loop you append all those slotMorningSum['tempo'] into the List
    list_.append(slotMorningSum['tempo'])

    print(slotMorningSum['tempo'])

#lastly, you combine them using pd.concat and do the sum()
concate = pd.concat(list_)
print(concate.sum())
```

Comment: That's work great, but the output is: `slot     7--87--87--87--87--87--87--87--87--87--87--8
tempo                                       10116.644
dtype: object` if i want only 10116.644 as output?

Comment: please change to use this `list_.append(slotMorningSum['tempo'])` before the `print(slotMorningSum['tempo'])`